# How to express you are not familiar with a field

Tags: phrases, expression-choice

I want to use this phrase: a lack of knowledge in (  ), but I'm not sure if it is typical.

I got stuck in a lab assignment that required some background knowledge of computer security, and I would like to get the background info from teaching assistants.

Can I use this sentence?  "Hi, I have a lack of knowledge in computer security, and I've searched the term XXX online, but I still didn't get it. Can you please explain to me what XXX means and where I suppose to look for XXX on the terminal."

Comment: I’d probably say that I was ***not well-versed*** in computer security and I’ve searched ***for*** the term... Then, by saying “I still didn’t get it” do you mean you found something on it but didn’t understand it or that you couldn’t find anything?  Also, are you asking them to actually explain it or just where to look for it?  And by “terminal” to you mean the internet or the computer?  I wouldn’t think you’re actually still using a terminal at this stage.

Comment: @Jim **Not well versed** -- good.

Comment: I intended to use "I still didn't get it" to mean that I found something on the term but didn't understand it. I was asking them to actually explain it or/and provide some helpful readings for me to read. The terminal means the terminal application on computer. Thank you for asking these questions that inspire me to clarify my sentences. Thank you @Jim

Comment: If you want to use "I have a lack of knowledge..." it would be better to say "I have a lack of knowledge _of_ ..." rather than "...a lack of knowledge _in_..."

Answer (score 1):

If you're ***completely ignorant*** of the subject, you ought to say:

**I'm unacquainted with computer security...**

or

**I'm unfamiliar with computer security...**

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, [Jim](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/17956/jim) wrote:

> I’d probably say that I was ***not well-versed*** in computer security and I’ve searched ***for*** the term.

If you're not [well-versed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/well-versed) in something, you don't know much about it.